# Javascript array of objects, search match based on partial string or substring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a search box, where user type a search query and dropdown start showing the matching result. I am trying the below function, which does return the matching values based on the quoteCategory, quoteText or the quoteAuthorName. **Problem** is it only return the object when the query matches in an array of object with **EXACT** words, for example, if user type **LOVE**, it will match and show the result in the dropdown, however when user type
**LOVE any other character** it does not show any result.

What I am trying to achieve is, if any word matches the user query in the array of objects, it should return the result. basically match should be based on the partial string or substring.

```
import React from 'react'

 
export const GlobalSearch = () => {

    const [textQuote, setTextQuote] = useContext({
{
            userId: '123',
            quoteAuthorName: 'Any Two',
            quoteCategory: 'Motivational',
            quoteType: 'textQuote',
            quoteText: 'If there’s no',
            
        },
        {
            userId: '124',
            quoteAuthorName: 'Any One',
            quoteCategory: 'Love',
            quoteType: 'textQuote',
            quoteText: 'If there’s no market, then it may not be one',
        }
)
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

let resultsObj = textQuote.filter(quote =>
            quote.quoteCategory.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
            || quote.quoteAuthorName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
            || quote.quoteText.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform the string in an Regex. An example using vanilla Javascript:

```
textQuote = [
                {
            userId: '123',
            quoteAuthorName: 'Any Two',
            quoteCategory: 'Motivational',
            quoteType: 'textQuote',
            quoteText: 'If there’s no',
            
        },
        {
            userId: '124',
            quoteAuthorName: 'Any One',
            quoteCategory: 'Love',
            quoteType: 'textQuote',
            quoteText: 'If there’s no market, then it may not be one',
        }
];
let searchTerm = "love is blind";

let searchArray = searchTerm.trim().split(" ");

let re = new RegExp(searchArray.join("|"), "i");

let resultsObj = textQuote.filter(quote =>
    re.test(quote.quoteCategory) ||
    re.test(quote.quoteAuthorName) ||
    re.test(quote.quoteText)
);

document.write(JSON.stringify(resultsObj));
```

Output:

```
[{"userId":"124","quoteAuthorName":"Any One","quoteCategory":"Love","quoteType":"textQuote","quoteText":"If there’s no market, then it may not be one"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need the same output when user query is 'love is blind'. but if the user query  'is blind' only it should NOT show any result.

Comment: Hi @TayyabRahman. It is not clear for me. Can you clarify this?

Comment: when user type the query, it shoud search and match from quoteCategory, quoteText or authorName, the match must be based on ONE or MORE words matching from the query string to the object or objects in the array. for example when user type LOVE, it will match quoteCategory, but when user type LOVE IS BLIND, now also it should match with quoteCategory as part of the string is matching. BUT when user type IS BLIND, now this query does not match with any quote category or quoteText. so it should not return any result.

Comment: Let's see if I understood: do you want to search using all words and return independently of the complete string, but any word. Is it right?

Comment: yes, correct. as long as any values match from the array of objects. it will return that object. If no word is matching from the complete string, then do not return result.

Comment: example 1. LOVE IS BLIND. will return 1 object. example 2: IS BLIND. will NOT return any result.

Comment: @TayyabRahman take a look in the code now. I believe now I have understood.

Comment: I tried, when i type LOVE IS BLIND it shows all the objects in the array, which is wrong, it should show only one object only. now when i type IS BLIND, it still shows all the objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217339/discussion-between-rafael-and-tayyab-rahman).

Answer (score -2):

You can try the search method of js

**UPDATED=====**

```
function findWordByReg(word, str) {
  return RegExp('\\b'+ word +'\\b').test(str)
}



let resultsObj = textQuote.filter(q=>
            findWordByReg(q.quoteCategory.toLowerCase(),searchTerm.toLowerCase())
            || findWordByReg(q.quoteAuthorName.toLowerCase(),searchTerm.toLowerCase())
            || findWordByReg(q.quoteText.toLowerCase(),searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried it, it returns all the objects in array regardless if the substring matches or not. e.g if search query is LOVE IS BLIND, the matching words are LOVE and it should show result but if the user type IS BLIND only, it should return no result.

Comment: how the result should be show? i mean can you give me an example format

Comment: when user type the query, it shoud search and match from quoteCategory, quoteText or authorName, the match must be based on ONE or MORE words matching from the query string to the object or objects in the array. for example when user type LOVE, it will match quoteCategory, but when user type LOVE IS BLIND, now also it should match with quoteCategory as part of the string is matching. BUT when user type IS BLIND, now this query does not match with any quote category or quoteText. so it should not return any result.

Comment: can you try my updated answer, this should solved the issue